# How to calculate thresholds (basic math)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I’m looking for an algorithm to calculate this in the most flexible way:

I’m working on a cost calculation and am searching for an elegant solution to solve the following problem:

The units (U) can be any number.

There can be an unlimited number of thresholds (T), but they all correlate with pricing (P) i.E.:

T: [10, 200, 1500, 2712]

P: [5,  4,   3,    1,   10]

Anything below 10 costs 5€,

Any unit between 10-200 costs 4€,

Any unit between 200-1500 costs 3€,

Any unit between 1500-2712 costs 1€,

Anything above 2712 costs 10€

So a unit of 1600 would cost:

50 (units from 0 to 10) + 760 (units from 10 to 200) + 3900 (units from 200 to 1500) + 100 (remaining 100 units that are above 1500) = 4810€

What would be a good way to calculate this?

While keeping in mind that ANY values are variable, all thresholds and corresponding prices and units can be anything at any time. (with the only fixed thing that Price always correlate with the thresholds)

€: I tried to do stuff with nested if/else statements but it’s a complete mess and not flexible at all since the threshold could also be more than 4 values…

Comment: So, what have you tried? Did you do any research? Did you write anything yet?

Comment: There is [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), if you want answers about number patterns. StackOverflow, is only about actual questions about the code

Comment: @igormilla: I read this as looking for a computer algorithm to calculate this which is completely on topic here.

Comment: Question: Am I right in thinking you are looking for a good algorithm to do this? And if so have you tried the obvious one which does exactly what you did in your example? If so what problem did you have with it and if not why not given that's exactly what you are doing when writing it out?

Comment: @Chris okey, after reading the question again, i think you are right, and it is very straight forward

Comment: @igormilla: What more needs defining? It seems like a perfectly well defined problem to me. There are two arrays, one with prices, one marking the price change thresholds. The method of calculating has been given in an example...

Comment: I’m looking for the cleanest way of writing a function for this. What I tried ended up in a mess… If it is "obvious" to you, it’s not to me, so please take the 5 seconds to post an example function. Thank you…

Comment: @chitzui: Am writing it up for you now. I realised after commenting that as you say it might not have been as obvious (particularly after rereading and seeing your comments on what you'd tried).

Comment: I've edited your question slightly to modify the tags and modify the language to be more accurate. Please look at what I've done and make sure you are happy with it and that I've not changed the question to something you didn't actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var T = [10, 200, 1500, 2712];
var P = [5, 4, 3, 1, 10];
function calculate(n){
    var i = 0;
    var current = 0;
    var cost = 0;
    while(n > 0 && i < T.length){
        var min = Math.min(T[i] - current, n);
        current += min;
        cost += P[i] * min;
        n -= min;
        i += 1;
    }
    if(n > 0){
        cost += P[i] * n;
    }
    return cost;
}
```

Here, I am keeping track of units for which cost has been calculated using the variable **current**. At the end I am checking if there are any unit left for which cost has not been calculated, I am multiplying the last element in P with the remaining units to get the total cost.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to slightly restate the problem. I would define a data structure that had an ordered list of number of units at a given price point.

So in your example of thresholds of I would make my new threshold array (BS for band size) this:

BS: [10, 190, 1300, 1212]

So `BS[0]` would be the same as `T[0]`. Then `BS[k]` would be `T[k]-T[k-1]`

With this in hand and our pricing array I'd use the following algorithm.

1. Set Remaining Units (R) equal to U.
2. Read next value from BS.
3. Is R > BS? If yes go to 4. If no go to 6.
4. Add BS*P to subtotal. Remove BS from R.
5. Is this the last value of BS? If yes go to 8. If no go to 2.
6. Add R*P to subtotal.
7. Go to 9.
8. Add R*FinalT to subtotal.
9. Finish.

This is effectively doing what you did in your example. You loop through your price bands adding on the full value for that range if your number goes past or if your total falls in a range adding that partial on.

I converted from T to BS just because it looks a bit neater (to me) to not have to do the calculation of the band size in the loop itself. The algorithm should be pretty straightforward to turn into code (a for loop and a couple of ifs should do the trick).